# pressing ctrl+D doesn't give complete output

Tags: python

I have the following code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def reducer():

    oldKey = None
    totalSales = 0

    for line in sys.stdin:
            data= line.strip().split("\t")
            if(len(data)!=2):
                    continue

            thisKey,thisSale = data

            if (oldKey and oldKey != thisKey):
                    print ("{}\t{}".format(oldKey,totalSales))
                    oldKey=thisKey
                    totalSales = 0


            oldKey = thisKey
            totalSales += float(thisSale)

    if(oldKey!=None):
            print("{}\t{}".format(oldKey,totalSales))

reducer()
```

When I give the input:

```
a       1
a       2
a       3
b       4
b       5
b       6
c       1
c       2
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> here

I get output:

```
a       6.0
b       15.0
```

I expected the output to be:

```
a       6.0
b       15.0
c       3.0
```

I am getting the full output only after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> once more. Why is it so? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

file-object iterations (`for line in sys.stdin: ..`) do internal buffering cause the behavior you observe.

By using `sys.stdin.readline()` with `while` loop, you can avoid it.

Change the following line:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

with:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
```

---

related PYTHON(1) manpage part:

> ```
>    -u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On
>           systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr  in
>           binary  mode.   Note that there is internal buffering in xread‐
>           lines(), readlines() and file-object iterators  ("for  line  in
>           sys.stdin")  which  is  not influenced by this option.  To work
>           around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside
>           a "while 1:" loop.
> ```